# a problem about set function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

If $\mu$ is monotone, subadditive and continuous from above  on $2^{\Omega}$ then it is continuous from below.

My idear is to prove $$\mu(\Omega) = \mu(A) + \mu(A^c), \forall A \in 2^{\Omega},$$ from the subadditive, the $\mu(\Omega) \leq \mu(A) + \mu(A^c)$ can be done easily. But how to prove $\mu(\Omega) \geq \mu(A) + \mu(A^c)$. Or there is another way to prove it. Thank you!

Comment: what's the relation between $\Omega$ and $A$?

Comment: for $A \in \Omega$?